# My input and button tags do not work due to my background animation

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, web-deployment

So, the problem is that the input fields for username and password are not working, along with the login button. Both of these are positioned on the rectangle, which itself is positioned on an svg tag.

Also, I believe that the problem is because I have an animated background for one of the div's on my body tag. The animation works but the input fields do not allow text to be entered, and the button does nothing when it's clicked on. I have tried giving the input fields and the button a z-index of 0, but nothing happened, so I just removed them.

The parts that I am having trouble with have an id of: loginButton, usernameInput, and passwordInput.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.homePage-background{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 3;
}

.animation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animation li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}

.animation li:nth-child(1){
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: -0s;
}

.animation li:nth-child(2){
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

.animation li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    animation-delay: 4s; /*Change this to 5.5 seconds later and see the result*/
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

#loginTitle{
    position: absolute;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: bold;
}



#username{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #dddddd;
}

#usernameInput{border-radius: 10px;}

#password{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 55%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #dddddd;
}

#passwordInput{border-radius: 10px;}

#loginButton{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-top: 65%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#loginButton:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homePage.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="homePage-background"> <!-- animation area-->
        <svg class="container-sm" width="400" height="760" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 35%; margin-top:35px">
            <rect id="loginRect" width="50%" height="100%" rx="40px" ry="40px" style="fill: cornflowerblue; stroke: pink; stroke-opacity: 0.0; stroke-width: 3px; "/>
            <foreignObject height="760" width="50%">

                <label id="username" for="usernameInput">UserName:
                    <input type="text" id="usernameInput" name="usernameInput" placeholder=" Enter your username ">
                </label>
                <label id="password" for="passwordInput">Password:
                    <input type="text" id="passwordInput" name="passwordInput" placeholder=" Enter your password">
                </label>
                <button type="submit" id='loginButton' value="Login" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp';">Login</button>
            </foreignObject>
        </svg>

        <ul class="animation"> <!-- box area-->
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was it necessary? This is where `z-index` will help. In css, I marked the edit.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.homePage-background{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 3;
}

.animation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animation li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}

.animation li:nth-child(1){
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: -0s;
}

.animation li:nth-child(2){
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

.animation li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    animation-delay: 4s; /*Change this to 5.5 seconds later and see the result*/
}

/*add this it*/
.container-sm {
    z-index: 9999;
}
/*---------------*/

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

#loginTitle{
    position: absolute;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-weight: bold;
}



#username{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #dddddd;
}

#usernameInput{border-radius: 10px;}

#password{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 55%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    color: #dddddd;
}

#passwordInput{border-radius: 10px;}

#loginButton{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-top: 65%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#loginButton:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homePage.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="homePage-background"> <!-- animation area-->
        <svg class="container-sm" width="400" height="760" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 35%; margin-top:35px">
            <rect id="loginRect" width="50%" height="100%" rx="40px" ry="40px" style="fill: cornflowerblue; stroke: pink; stroke-opacity: 0.0; stroke-width: 3px; "/>
            <foreignObject height="760" width="50%">

                <label id="username" for="usernameInput">UserName:
                    <input type="text" id="usernameInput" name="usernameInput" placeholder=" Enter your username ">
                </label>
                <label id="password" for="passwordInput">Password:
                    <input type="text" id="passwordInput" name="passwordInput" placeholder=" Enter your password">
                </label>
                <button type="submit" id='loginButton' value="Login" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp';">Login</button>
            </foreignObject>
        </svg>

        <ul class="animation"> <!-- box area-->
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation you currently use has a `z-index: 3`

You should add a higher `z-index` value (4 or more, whatever you feel is convenient) to the container.

```
.container-sm {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkBurnsRed/37se02cr/7/